# How to use the .clearfix class?

Tags: css, html, html5boilerplate, boilerplate

I think I'm misunderstanding the concept of the `.clearfix` class. Maybe somebody can help me out.

I'm looking for a way to use `float` and `clear` without messing up my markup. So I thought, that's where `.clearfix` can be used for.

Inside of an empty H5BP-project, my markup looks like:

```
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Below the result. I was expecting a tic tac toe-field, though. Can somebody tell me:

1. How I can achieve my goal and
2. What the `.clearfix` class really can be used for?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `clearfix` class is used on a container of which all the children are floating. If you would not use this, the container would not get any height (except in IE). http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/

What you are after is not a `clearfix`, but just a `clear`. You could make a class
`.clear { clear: both;}`
and apply that one instead of the `clearfix` you are using now.

If you want to learn more about `clearfix`, there is plenty of information out there:
[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

I have set up a small example to demonstrate the use of `clearfix` and `clear`: http://jsfiddle.net/hjXMG/1

Answer (score 6):

- **Clearfix** is added **around** floating blocks
- *Clear* is added *after* floating blocks