# Why is my clearfix not working?

Tags: css

This is a clearfix that I found on the internet. I have 3 columns and I am trying to put the clearfix after the far right column.

```
.right::after{
   content: " ";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

However it does not clear the floats... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example? Your HTML and CSS.

Comment: [Force Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) might help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the .clearfix class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013362/how-to-use-the-clearfix-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using double `::`, try using one `:`

```
.right:before,
.right:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

To make a clearfix work, you need to wrap your floats in a container that has the clearfix:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">first</div>
    <div class="left">second</div>
    <div class="left">third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following clearfix hack:

```
.right:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
```